# VB6 Dim varCode As String * 2

Tags: vb6

what does this mean? 
`Dim varCode As String * 2`

From my basic understanding, it means string multiply 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring a string with a length of 2.

See also: [String Length Declaration for Visual Basic 6.0 Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f47b0zy4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

That is the syntax for a fixed length string in VB6

Answer (score 2):

It means that the variable has a

> LIMIT on how many characters it will hold.

**Important Note:**

Even if the string is **empty**, it will represent 2 Empty Spaces.

Example, Having:

> Dim MyVar * 100

would store in a Database 100 Empty spaces if you have not set it value.

*It's important to know that to save Memory and DiskSpace.*

Please Rate my Answer!!